# Does upgrading to Amazon RDS multi-az interrupt i/o ops of a running instance?

Tags: amazon-rds

If I upgrade a single-az RDS instance to a multi-az instance, will that interrupt the i/o operations of my current instance in the same way that taking a database snapshot normally would? Or, will my current instance continue to run as normal, with no impact to my app, while the second multi-az db instance was provisioned and brought online?

I do realize upgrading from small to large does impact i/o operations for a few minutes. This would simply be bringing up a new instance of the same size/configuration in a different az, using their nice GUI tools now available on the web.

I was unable to locate an answer in the Amazon docs, and was hoping someone on stack has experience here.

Thanks!

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549454/two-questions-regarding-aws-rds-multi-az

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes, briefly, according to experts at amazon.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=57845&tstart=0

Comment: It would be helpful to clarify what "brief" means in this case.